# In layman's terms, why is Naive Bayes the dominant algorithm used for text-classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining, naive-bayes

While I realize choosing the "right" algorithm can vary depending on the task at hand, I'm curious as to why Naive Bayes is quite often used for things like spam-classification or sentiment-analysis.

What's the giveaway in a dataset that screams: "Use Naive Bayes on me!"?

Comment: It's not dominant, it's just very simple and does a decent job.

Answer (score 6):

I'm taking your word for Naive Bayes' popularity here as language processing isn't my specialty:

One reason NB is useful is the bias–variance tradeoff. Spam/sentiment type data are often noisy and usually high-dimensional (more predictors than samples, $n \ll p$). The naive assumption that predictors are independent of one another is a strong, high-bias, one.

By assuming independence of predictors we're saying that covariance matrix of our model only has non-zero entries on the diagonal. Since estimating covariance structure in $n \ll p$ situations is very hard indeed we are usually forced to put some constraints on the problem. The independence assumption is a particularly strong constraint that yields a highly interpretable model. The introduced bias may sufficiently reduce variance that you get better predictions.